# text top center aligment on picture

Tags: html, css, alignment

So I want what text be on image  and horizontally centered. And then the windows is resized it still be there.[image: It have look like that.]
Now it is in the bottom of image.

```css
.main_image {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.image_text {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.main_text {
  font-size: 38.889px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main_subtext {
  font-size: 22.222px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.988);
}
```

```html
<figure class="images_class">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sOCyriP.png" alt="" class="main_image" />
  <figcaption class="image_text">
    <div class="main_text">Main text</div>
    <div class="main_subtext">Subtext</div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should position text `absolute` in a `relative` container.

```css
.images_class {
  position: relative;
}
.main_image {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.image_text {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0
}
.main_text {
  font-size: 38.889px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main_subtext {
  font-size: 22.222px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.988);
}
```

```html
<figure class="images_class">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sOCyriP.png" alt="" class="main_image" />
  <figcaption class="image_text">
    <div class="main_text">Main text</div>
    <div class="main_subtext">Subtext</div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/jpqubt9y/1/)

```
  position: absolute
  width:100%
  margin: auto
```

To your image text.

If you want to add something in the center which takes 100% width, You have to use `width:100% and margin:auto` .